# Need to rotate text in a label every time user refresh the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, rotation

I have a label called lblMessage. The data of the message is saved in a SQL Server 2005 DB. In my table i have a message ID and then 4 rows with my message ID. Message 1, Message 2, Message 3 and Message 4.

I want my lblMessage to go through a loop every time the user refresh his browser, so that when he refresh it once the next message will be Message 2..... and so on and so on.

How would i do this in VB.NET or C#?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**VB.NET**

```
Private Shared messageNumber as Integer

Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Select Case messageNumber
        Case 0
            lblMessage.Text = MESSAGE_1
        Case 1
            lblMessage.Text = MESSAGE_2
        Case 2
            lblMessage.Text = MESSAGE_3
        Case 3
            lblMessage.Text = MESSAGE_4
    End Select
    messageNumber = (messageNumber + 1) Mod 4
End Sub
```

**C#**

```
private static int messageNumber;

public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    switch (messageNumber) {
        case 0:
            lblMessage.Text = MESSAGE_1;
            break;
        case 1:
            lblMessage.Text = MESSAGE_2;
            break;
        case 2:
            lblMessage.Text = MESSAGE_3;
            break;
        case 3:
            lblMessage.Text = MESSAGE_4;
            break;
    }
    messageNumber = (messageNumber + 1) % 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe the table schema in your question, so I don't know if your message table contains anything other than a message ID and the message.  If you can add another column, you could call it something like sequence and make it a tinyint.

Now, when fetching your message, you need to specify both the message id and the sequence number.

Every time you refresh, you increment the sequence number and get its modulo to 4 (so that sequence is always 0, 1, 2 or 3).

something like:

```
sequence = sequence++ % 4;
lblMessage.Text = fetchMessage(MessageID, sequence);
```

and fetchMessage simply performs your query:

```
Select  message
  From  tbl_Messages
  Where messageID = @messageID
        and sequence = @sequence
```